# Make the width of an asp listbox the same the tablecell's

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table with 2 rows and 4 cells. The 1st and second cells are 30% width of table  and the 3rd and forth sit top of each other again 30% width making total of 90%.

Iv tried putting listbox cells into panels and setting their width to 30%, putting cell width to 30% and a few other things but width still ignored.

The table itself should be 100% width of the screen. 
[image]

My listboxes keep expanding to more than their allocated 30% though, how can I stop this?

Update: I got the listbox to stop overflowing but not the listbox is sometimes smaller than the cell - can I get it to match the cell width all the time whether the text is shorter or longer than the width?

```
<div style="overflow: hidden">
<asp:Table runat="server" Width="100%" GridLines="Horizontal">
    <asp:TableRow Width="100%">
        <asp:TableCell RowSpan="2">
            <asp:ListBox ID="JsonAppKeyListBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Rows="20" BackColor="#66CCFF" ForeColor="White" onselectedindexchanged="JsonListBox_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:ListBox>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell RowSpan="2">
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlParentNodes" runat="server" Width="100%">
                <asp:ListBox ID="JsonAppsValueListBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Rows="20" BackColor="#66CCFF" ForeColor="White" Width="100%">
                </asp:ListBox>
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="30%">
             <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnBack" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/analysis/analysis_back_logo.png" Width="30px" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
             <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/analysis/analysis_delete_logo.png" Width="30px"/>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnConfirm" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/analysis/analysis_confirmed_logo.png" Width="30px"/>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_nodeNotes" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="100%" BackColor="#66CCFF" ForeColor="White" Rows="30" TextMode="MultiLine">
            </asp:TextBox>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it. needed to set the listbox, cells and the rows to 30, 30 and 100 percent respectively

```
<div style="overflow: hidden">
<asp:Table runat="server" Width="100%" GridLines="Horizontal">
    <asp:TableRow Width="100%">
        <asp:TableCell RowSpan="2" Width="30%">
            <asp:ListBox ID="JsonAppKeyListBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Rows="20" BackColor="#66CCFF" ForeColor="White" onselectedindexchanged="JsonListBox_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="100%">
            </asp:ListBox>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell RowSpan="2" Width="30%">
                <asp:ListBox ID="JsonAppsValueListBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Rows="20" BackColor="#66CCFF" ForeColor="White" Width="100%" Height="100%">
                </asp:ListBox>

        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="30%">
             <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnBack" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/analysis/analysis_back_logo.png" Width="30px" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
             <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/analysis/analysis_delete_logo.png" Width="30px"/>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnConfirm" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/analysis/analysis_confirmed_logo.png" Width="30px"/>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_nodeNotes" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="100%" BackColor="#66CCFF" ForeColor="White" Rows="30" TextMode="MultiLine">
            </asp:TextBox>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
</div>
```